# Running multiple threads concurrenty using ScheduledExecutorService

Tags: java

The below code executes a file transfer task periodically. I want to do another file copy task at same time from different location by calling the same method.For that i created another runnable2 and executor2 instances and executed. How to do multiple tasks using a single instance instead of creating multiple instances.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
          public void run() {

            File srcFolder = new File("c:\\location1\\Test1\\");
            File destFolder = new File("d:\\location1\\Test1\\");

            if(!srcFolder.exists()){
               System.out.println("Directory does not exist.");
               System.exit(0);
            }else{
               try{
                copyFolder(srcFolder,destFolder);
               }catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.exit(0);
               }
            }
            System.out.println("Done");           
            }
        };

    ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);    
    executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnable, 0, 300, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

Comment: Well, you just create a single instance of executor, and call its scheduleAtFixedRate() method twice (once for each task).

Comment: Okay. Is there any other way to do this. Here only my file locations change other than that i call the same method again.

Comment: You asked how to use a single instance of executor. I told you how to do that. Now you're asking for another way. So I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry if i have framed the question wrong. I wanted to know about more elegant way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are going to do the same operation more than one time, then creating a class is better than anonymous class (make it have 2 params in constructor):

```
public class FileCopy implements Runnable {

    private String src="", dest = "";
    public FileCopy(String src, String dest){
        this.src  = src;
        this.dest = dest;
    }

    @override
    public void run(){
        File srcFolder = new File(src);
        File destFolder = new File(dest);

        if(!srcFolder.exists()){
           System.out.println("Directory does not exist.");
           //System.exit(0);
        }else{
           try{
            copyFolder(srcFolder,destFolder);
           }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            //System.exit(0);
           }
        }
        System.out.println("Done"); 
    }//run
}
```

now you can make as many instances as you want, pass different params each time, and execute the **Runnable**

```
ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);    
executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new FileCopy(src1, dest1), 0, 300, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new FileCopy(src2, dest2), 0, 300, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

**Notes:** :

- may be you need to change this `newScheduledThreadPool(1)` to `newScheduledThreadPool(2)`? not so sure
- `System.exit(0);` is not an option now, in case of errors, because you have multiple instances running, if one has a problem, that should not mean closing the whole app, you need to implement another way to handle errors

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation. It worked. Just one thing. Both ThreadPool 1 and 2 worked. Is it fine to do with 1 ?

Comment: @user7620991 i am not sure about this exactly, i think it's the count of threads to remain in pool one finished. so it's not like an upper limit of allowed threads to run. i can't be sure about this point though

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the answer.